# How can I change the frequency of a wav file in node.js?

Tags: node.js, file, wav, frequency

I have a short wav file. This file has a musical note of an instrument recorded, for example: piano playing B3 or 246,942 Hz(pb3.wav), or violin plaing F♯6 or 1479,98 Hz (vfzs6.wav).

I want node.js to save a new wav file based on the file pb3.wav, but played on C4 (261,626 Hz) or D4 (293,665 Hz).

Actually, I can get wav file's frequency, and I have a list for each musical note.

Comment: Have you tried using node-lame? You can check it out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-lame